# python tensorflow 2.0 build a simple LSTM network without using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to build a tensorflow LSTM network without using Keras API. The model is very simple:

1. input of sequence of 4 word indices
2. embedding input 100 dim word vector
3. pass through LSTM layer
4. dense layer with output of sequence of 4 words

Loss function is sequence loss.

I have the following code:

```
# input
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[config.batch_size, config.num_steps], name='Input')
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[config.batch_size, config.num_steps], name='Target')

# embedding
embedding = tf.get_variable('Embedding', initializer=embedding_matrix, trainable=False)
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_placeholder)
inputs = [tf.squeeze(x, axis=1) for x in tf.split(inputs, config.num_steps, axis=1)]

# LSTM
initial_state = tf.zeros([config.batch_size, config.hidden_size])
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(config.hidden_size)
output, _ = tf.keras.layers.RNN(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, unroll=True)

# loss op
all_ones = tf.ones([config.batch_size, config.num_steps])
cross_entropy = tfa.seq2seq.sequence_loss(output, labels_placeholder, all_ones, vocab_size)
tf.add_to_collection('total_loss', cross_entropy)
loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('total_loss'))

# projection (dense)
proj_U = tf.get_variable('Matrix', [config.hidden_size, vocab_size])
proj_b = tf.get_variable('Bias', [vocab_size])
outputs = [tf.matmul(o, proj_U) + proj_b for o in output]
```

The problem I have is at the LSTM part now:

```
# tensorflow 1.x
output, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
        lstm_cell, inputs, dtype = tf.float32, 
        sequence_length = [config.num_steps]*config.batch_size)
```

I'm having problem converting this to tensorlow 2. In above code, I'm getting the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 outputs, _ = tf.keras.layers.RNN(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, unroll=True)
>
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable RNN object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work for TensorFlow 2.X.

```
import tensorflow as tf
# input
input_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[config.batch_size, config.num_steps], name='Input')
labels_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[config.batch_size, config.num_steps], name='Target')

# embedding
embedding = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Embedding', initializer=embedding_matrix, trainable=False)
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=embedding, ids=input_placeholder)
inputs = [tf.squeeze(x, axis=1) for x in tf.split(inputs, config.num_steps, axis=1)]

# LSTM
initial_state = tf.zeros([config.batch_size, config.hidden_size])
lstm_cell = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(config.hidden_size)
output, _ = tf.keras.layers.RNN(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, unroll=True)

# loss op
all_ones = tf.ones([config.batch_size, config.num_steps])
cross_entropy = tfa.seq2seq.sequence_loss(output, labels_placeholder, all_ones, vocab_size)
tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection('total_loss', cross_entropy)
loss = tf.add_n(tf.compat.v1.get_collection('total_loss'))

# projection (dense)
proj_U = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Matrix', [config.hidden_size, vocab_size])
proj_b = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Bias', [vocab_size])
outputs = [tf.matmul(o, proj_U) + proj_b for o in output]

# tensorflow 1.x
output, _ = tf.compat.v1.nn.static_rnn(
        lstm_cell, inputs, dtype = tf.float32, 
        sequence_length = [config.num_steps]*config.batch_size)
```