# How to implement Tensorflow LSTM equivalent of Keras with return_sequence and return_state params?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0

In Keras one would usually write:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n, input_shape=(ntimesteps, nfeatures), 
    return_sequences=return_sequences, return_state=return_state))
```

How do you emulate `return_sequences` and `return_state` features **in pure Tensorflow 2**?

Answer (score 0):

Keras is the high-level API of TensorFlow 2, so you would do the same, the only difference is that you do not import keras anymore, but

```py
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__) # 2.x

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(n, input_shape=(ntimesteps, nfeatures), 
    return_sequences=return_sequences, return_state=return_state))
```

Comment: Oscar the question is to implement in pure Tensorflow without keras. Not importing keras does not make it not-keras.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get why you do not want to use keras as a tensorflow API.

In any case, this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115646/python-tensorflow-2-0-build-a-simple-lstm-network-without-using-keras might help.

Comment: it doesnt help. i am not asking how to port keras lstm in general to TF but of 2 specific parameters. thanks